# No connection to default gateway

Tags: netplan, network-bonding

I freshly installed a new ubuntu server and set up netplan for 802.3ad. Now I can reach every device in my network (and vice versa) but not the gateway and therefor the internet (also the router cannot reach the server). The server is directly plugged into the gateway (like every other device). I don't have any iptables rules set. Does anybody have an idea what could be causing this?

This is my netplan config:

```
network:
  bonds:
    bond0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.88.11/24
      gateway4: 192.168.88.1
      interfaces:
        - eno1
        - eno2
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 192.168.88.4
      parameters:
        lacp-rate: fast
        mode: 802.3ad
        transmit-hash-policy: layer3+4
  ethernets:
    eno1: {}
    eno2: {}
  version: 2
```

Note: DNS is working fine

Comment: Are you sure your router has really 192.168.88.1 IP ?

Comment: yes (every other device uses this address too)